# ¿Cómo generar código correlativo?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto contable web en asp.net mvc y necesito generar un numero auto-incremental de un rango de 7, por ejemplo el primer numero seria 0000001, el segundo 0000002 y así sucesivamente
¿Como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: intentaste algo? que problema particular tuviste?

Comment: Usa un bucle con `yield`.

Comment: @gbianchi No, aun no, no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas pensando de forma incorrecta, en la db no se pone el formato numerico, los ceros delante del numeros estan de mas

lo que tienes que comseguir es la secuencia, el formato con ceros delante solo lo pones cuando vayas a mostras el valor en pantalla

la secuencia la puedes realizar con un campo del tipo IDENTITY, o sino usando

SELECT MAX(campo) WHERE Tabla

a ese valor por supuesto le sumas uno para tene el siguiente

pero remarco en la db solo el valor 1, 2, 3, y nada mas, los ceros delante lo agregas al mostrar el valor usando

textbox1.Text = string.Format("{0:000}", numero);

esta y otra respuesta en el link
[Numeros Correlativos C# y SQL](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/0110cc46-b96e-4c5f-bbeb-b9022f000f6b/numeros-correlativos-c-y-sql?forum=netfxwebes)

Comment: entendí muy bien tu respuesta y es la mejor manera de hacer esto, lo único que no me queda claro es el textbox1.Text = string.Format("{0:000}", numero), si el código lo voy a mostrar en un textboxFor en la view